# Adding multiple tags when creating a VM

Tags: tags, virtual-machine, addition

Using the code below to create VM with two tags, only the last one remains. Documentations says to use --tags=TAG,[TAG,…] but that does not work. Any help would be great. Thanks. I have tried the following, with several variations, but it does not work:

```
gcloud compute instances create vm-1 \
    --image-project windows-cloud \
    --image-family windows-2016 \
    --tags allowhttp \
    --tags allowprivaterdp \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --boot-disk-size 77GB \
    --boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
    --network-interface '' \
    --network-interface subnet=ssubnet,private-network-ip=192.168.64.22
```

Tried to add multiple parms with and without commas, brackets, quotes and GCP does not like it. I don't want to add the tags as a separate step, `gcloud compute instances add-tags vm-b --zone us-east1-b --tags mytags`, since it appears this could be easily added at creation just don't have the right syntax it appears. Documentations says to use `--tags=TAG,[TAG,…]` but that does not work.

Expected to see two tags added to the VM, only the last one remains and other syntax changes dont allow the VM to be created

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, I would answer it as it is unanswered,

the correct syntax to add multiple tags to a VM instance while its creation is as follows:

```
gcloud compute instances create www1 \
```

--image-family debian-9 
--image-project debian-cloud 
--zone us-central1-a 
--machine-type=n1-standard-1 
--subnet=default 
--tags network-lb-tag1,network-lb-tag2,network-lb-tag3

This assigns 3 tags to the instance upon its creation.
[image: Image displaying that the assigned 3 tags were added to the instance]

The documentation correctly specifies it as --tags=TAG,[TAG,…], which means if there are multiple tags to be added, its value should be added in continuation to the 1st value separated by a comma.

-Ak